# Making a background slideshow not full screen?

Tags: html, css

So I got this [Fullscreen Background Image Slideshow](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/) from tympanus :) You can definitely see the codes on the site linked above... now I do not want it to be taking the whole page... I want to add margins all over... I've been trying to do it but no avail. I tried reducing the size of the background image into lesser percent but it's still not proportioned...

How do I add an equal padding to the slideshow? :(

```
.cb-slideshow li span {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
color: transparent;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: none;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 0;
animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
```

Comment: One way you could do it is by changing the width/height to `calc(100% - 50px)` where `50px` is twice the margin you want all the way around then use `margin-left:25px; margin-top:25px`, using the margin value you want. Another option is to put it in a container with `position:relative;` and size/position the container the way you want to

Answer (score 0):

I think the absolute simplest way is to do like this:

```
.cb-slideshow li span {
left: 5%;                   // alter as you like
top: 5%;                    // alter as you like
width: 90%;                 // alter as you like
height: 90%;                // alter as you like
position: absolute;
color: transparent;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: none;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 0;
animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
```